# How do I insert a code block on Pages on Mac?

Tags: macos, codeblocks

I'm trying to insert a code block on a Pages document on mac, and the only way is to copy paste from other text editors.
Does anyone know a way?
Like a plugin for pages or something?

If you know there isn't a way pls write it

Answer (score 0):

At least here it says that it's not possible.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/424483

Comment: the referenced article is outdated (2006).

Comment: @simplikios you are welcome to update it then